# Use MPMoviePlayerController with AVCaptureSession

Tags: iphone, xcode, mpmovieplayercontroller, avcapturesession

Having issue.  My View has an MPMoviePlayerController playing, and also uses AVCaptureSession to record both audio and video.  The video will record fine by itself, but when I add the input to the session for it, the record stops and video gets corrupted.  If I don't use the MPMoviePlayerController, it will record audio and video fine.  What can I do to make the recording work with MPMoviePlayerController running?

**Edit:**

Making progress...

Added the following code & results improved.

previewlayer no longer freezes, and the resulting recording is finally more than 2.2 kb. 
If sound or video alone, its fine, if both file is corrupt

```
AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance]; 
UInt32 allowMixing = true; 
OSStatus status = AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryMixWithOthers, sizeof(allowMixing), &allowMixing); 
error = nil; 
if (![audioSession setActive:YES error:&error]) 
{ 
    NSLog(@"AVAudioSession setActive:YES failed: %@", [error localizedDescription]); 
}
```

EDIT:
No, it doesn't work.  Sometimes it will, sometimes the preview layer won't even show a preview, and sometimes the video won't even output.  Back to square 1.

Comment: Try using instruments and check if the CPU is too busy to do both at the same time.

Comment: It is not too busy...behaving like MPMovieplayercontroller gets the priority, and stops the avcapturesession the moment mpmovieplayercontroller begins playback.

Comment: I have never tried what you are doing but maybe the results are better when using `AVPlayer` as that one gives you a lot more flexibility and transparency on what is happening.

Comment: Tried that one earlier, and it had the exact same results.  Everything works perfectly if I just record video while mpmovieplayercontroller playing...it's just the audio messing it all up.

Comment: making progress.  added the following code, & results improved.  previewlayer no longer freezes, and the resulting recording is finally more than 2.2 kb.  If sound or video alone, its fine, if both file is corrupt
` AVAudioSession* audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
UInt32 allowMixing = true;
OSStatus status = AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryMixWithOthers, sizeof(allowMixing), &allowMixing);
error = nil;
    if (![audioSession setActive:YES error:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"AVAudioSession setActive:YES failed: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }`

Comment: +1 need me too similar, just audio recording, but AVAudioRecorder will stop the player and I can't hear, what I am recording